# Method run() is not executed

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using java. I'm trying to execute a thread, but the issue I'm getting is 
`thread.start()` method is getting executed, but as we know when we call the `start` method of thread, the `run()` method gets called internally. 
But in my case the `run()` method is not getting executed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    parseArguments(args);

    ScraperStore scraperStore = ScraperStore.getInstance();
    SocialSiteManager siteManager = new SocialSiteManager();
    sitesToScrape = siteManager.getSocialSitesToScrape();

    for (SocialSite site : sitesToScrape) {
        ScrapeThread srThread = new ScrapeThread("srThread");
        Thread scraper = new Thread(srThread);
        srThread.setSiteToScrape(site);
        srThread.setPageTypeToScrape(startPageToScrape);
        srThread.setTypeToScrape(typeToScrape);
        ArrayList<String> listOfValues = ScraperStore.getNextUrlToScrape(startPageToScrape, site);
        srThread.setTypeToScrape(typeToScrape);

        try {
            srThread.setUrlOwnedBy(listOfValues.get(0));
            srThread.setStartUrl(listOfValues.get(1));
            scraper.start();

            boolean state = scraper.isAlive();
            scrapeThreads.add(scraper);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thread class:

```
class ScrapeThread {

    public ScrapeThread(String threadName) {
        thread = new Thread(this,threadName);
        System.out.println(thread.getName());
    }

}
```

Run method:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("in the run method");
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium(config.getHost(), Integer.parseInt(config.getPort()), 
                config.getBrowser(), config.getUrl());
        selenium.start();
        Integer count = 0;

        while (startUrl != null) {
            HtmlPage homePage = new HtmlPage();
            homePage.setCreatedBy(new String());
            homePage.setCreatedon(new String());
            homePage.setModifiedBy(new String());
            homePage.setModifiedOn(new String());
            homePage.setNoOfItemsFound(new String());
            homePage.setOwnedBy(urlOwnedBy);
            homePage.setPageType(scraper.getPageTypeToScrape());
            homePage.setPageUrl(startUrl);

            proxy = getInitialisedProxy();
            scraper.setNavigator(proxy.getNavigator());
            scraper.setStartUrl(startUrl);

            try {
                scraper.initialize();
            } catch (MyException e) {
                if (status == false){
                    throw new Exception(MyException.NOTFOUND);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using sellinium. Is there any chance that I'm getting the issue because of selenium?

Comment: dont think selenium would affect this.  show some code?

Comment: Actually my thread's run() method has some selenium code as selenium.start() so whats happening is when i m directly calling the run() method ,selenium is working fine but when i m doing normal thread execution i.e. i m calling the thread.start() method then selenium is giving issue.what could be teh issue sir..?

Comment: is ScrapeThread implementing Runnable ?

Comment: Hello sir!!yes my ScrapeThread class is implementing the Runnable.

Answer (score 1):

Look at code and compare it with your code.

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
   Runnable inst=new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
        {
           System.out.println("Thread statement!");
         }
     };

   Thread thrd=new Thread(inst);
   thrd.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you come to know run method is not executed . didu u put a trace on the run method?

```
//Old
new Thread(niidleThread,"scraper"); scraper.start()

// new
new Thread(srThread);  or
new Thread(srThread,"scraper");
```

Try the new one i have given above;

Comment: now the problem is two lines in run method are getting executed and after that the execution is returning back to main() method and executing the next code in main().what could be the issue sir?i checked the value for the statement at which the execution is getting the problem but that value is also proper.

Answer (score 0):

Just from a cursory review of your code... I see that you might have gone a little thread-happy. Consider:

```
ScrapeThread srThread = new ScrapeThread("srThread"); // This is creating your ScrapeThread object (which should really implement the Runnable interface)
    Thread scraper = new Thread(srThread); // This is creating a thread which wraps another thread... take this out.
    srThread.setSiteToScrape(site);
    srThread.setPageTypeToScrape(startPageToScrape);
    srThread.setTypeToScrape(typeToScrape);
    ArrayList<String> listOfValues =              ScraperStore.getNextUrlToScrape(startPageToScrape, site);
        srThread.setTypeToScrape(typeToScrape);
        try {
            srThread.setUrlOwnedBy(listOfValues.get(0));
            srThread.setStartUrl(listOfValues.get(1));
            scraper.start(); // You would want to replace this with srThread.start(); once fixing the items I addressed above
            boolean state=scraper.isAlive();
            scrapeThreads.add(scraper);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial might help you out a bit.

Comment: hello seth!!but my ScrapeThread  class dont have start method so i m wrapping the ScrapeThread object in Thread object and calling start().